Compositor Not Applying in Render
I have a clip with a greenscreen I'd like to key out with the Compositor. However, when I go to render, it just renders the original footage without the keying applied. I've been reading forums and trying a few methods, but haven't had success yet.



The file format you are using is set to Color > RGB, not RGBA, so it does not save the transparency.

By the way, if you do not want to use the mask in any other way but just to make the background transparent, you can simply use the Image output of the Keying node without the need to plug a Set Alpha node inbetween (and at least when I use it here, the result from the direct Image output looks better than using the Matte output in a Set Alpha node).
